# I expected a `numpy.lib.polynomial.poly1d` object, I've found a sequence of integers

Tags: python, numpy

```
In [31]: print(np.poly1d((3,2)))                                                          

3 x + 2

In [32]: a = np.array(( np.poly1d((3,2)), np.poly1d((3,2)) ))
```

I expected that array `a` were a `(2,)` shaped array of `numpy.lib.polynomial.poly1d` objects, BUT

```
In [33]: a.shape                                                                          
Out[33]: (2, 2)

In [34]: type(a[0,0])                                                                     
Out[34]: numpy.int64

In [35]: a                                                                                
Out[35]: 
array([[2, 2],
       [2, 2]])
```

What's going on?

---

It's worth to be mentioned that

```
 In [36]: a = np.array(( np.poly1d((3,2,1)), np.poly1d((3,2,1)) ))
```

raises an error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-3139075221f6> in <module>
----> 1 a = np.array(( np.poly1d((3,2,1)), np.poly1d((3,2,1)), np.poly1d((3,2,1)) ))

ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 2 to array axis with dimension 3
```

Comment: Why not make `a` a list of those objects. What's an object array going to do for you?

Comment: @hpaulj I was motivated by the idea of  computing polynomial products using 
a 2D array of polynomials and an outer product,  `einsum('ik,jk->kij', a,a)`.  I have already a working solution using a list of lists and a multiple list comprehension.

Comment: I don't think an object dtype array will work in `einsum`.

Comment: @hpaulj  Sigh, it's exactly so: `TypeError: invalid data type for einsum`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `poly1d` object is iterable

```
In [1]: np.poly1d((3,2))                                                        
Out[1]: poly1d([3, 2])
In [2]: list(_)                                                                 
Out[2]: [3, 2]
```

`np.array` tries to makes a multidimensional numeric array from its inputs, iterating where possible.  That's why making an array from these `poly1d` object ends up looking like you did `np.array([[3,2],[3,2]])`.

The most reliable way to create an object dtype array is to initialize a 'blank' one and fill it.

```
In [12]: arr = np.empty(2, object)                                              
In [13]: arr[:] = [np.poly1d((3,2)), np.poly1d((4,2))]                          
In [14]: arr                                                                    
Out[14]: array([poly1d([3, 2]), poly1d([4, 2])], dtype=object)
```

But do you really need an object dtype array?  Why not stick with a list of the `poly1d` objects?

===

We've observed in other SO that attempting to create a object dtype array can go several different ways.  Some times it works, sometimes you get a numeric array, and sometimes an error.

```
In [17]: np.array([np.poly1d((3,2)), np.poly1d((3,2,1))])                       
Out[17]: array([poly1d([3, 2]), poly1d([3, 2, 1])], dtype=object)
In [18]: np.array([np.poly1d((3,2,1)), np.poly1d((3,2,1))])                     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-00b20d14a2b6> in <module>
----> 1 np.array([np.poly1d((3,2,1)), np.poly1d((3,2,1))])

ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 2 to array axis with dimension 3
```

Comment: ... and `arr**2` gives `array([poly1d([ 9, 12,  4]), poly1d([16, 16,  4])], dtype=object)` as expected

Comment: Math operations on object dtype arrays are hit-or-miss.  They delegate the action to a corresponding method for each object.  In this case it works because `np.poly1d((2,3))**2` works, it has a `__pow__` method.  When it works this action is convenient, but it isn't faster than list comprehension.